# Python and GTK3 errors printed to stderr, what are they?

Tags: python, gtk3, glade

In my Python 2.7 + GTK+3 + PyGI + GUI made with Glade3 app I get a lot of errors like this:

```
(python.exe:81868): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_device_get_source: assertion 'GDK_IS_DEVICE (device)' failed
```

There is no exception happening in Python and nothing is behaving wrong in the program. They seem to be harmless, but for cleanliness, I would like to stop them from happening.

I've noticed that this happens for example when activating and deactivating a menu item, or changing the selection on a combo box. I've tried to set a callback that does nothing on the events that trigger the problem, but no change.

So, what do they mean? How do I stop them?

Comment: Now my errors are fatal... `(python.exe:66232): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_text_attributes_ref: assertion 'values != NULL' failed` and my program dies. Is there a list of explanations of Gtk errors? If I run in the python debugger it doesn't happen! Anyone?

Answer (score 2):

Such messages are emitted by code which use the Glib debugging functions, see [1], when an assertion fails. These assertions are used by Glib and many components built on Glib to report invalid states, invalid arguments, etc.

Often, such messages hint at errors in ones application, so it is a good idea to search for the cause. To do this, export the `G_DEBUG` environment with the appropriate value, see [2]. In your case, you would set `G_DEBUG=fatal-criticals`, and the program will abort when a critical message is emitted. If you then run your application in `gdb` and print a backtrace when the program aborts, you should get an idea of what did lead to the message being emitted. Remember to install debuginfo packages for glib and gtk/gdk to obtain usable backtraces.

To disable the messages from being emitted, if you are not able to fix the issue (possibly because the cause is not your code, but i.e. some other library), you can look at `g_log_set_handler`, see [3].

- [1] https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Warnings-and-Assertions.html
- [2] https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-running.html
- [3] https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Message-Logging.html

Comment: These errors are completely unrelated to my code. They happen when interacting with the GUI even if there are no handlers. The GUI has been put together with Glade3. My program is in Python so I cannot debug what's happening inside GLib

Comment: GLib.log_set_handler() does not exist in PiGI! It's mentioned in the docs, but it's not there.

Comment: You can debug what is happening inside glib by just running python through gdb: `gdb python myapp.py`. As for `set_log_handler`, I fear you are right, see https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=670507 .